# How many binary strings of length 2n + 1 have more 1's than 0's? Use bijection to prove.

Tags: combinatorics

***NOTE: This is a homework question, so I only ask for hints and suggestions to nudge me in the correct direction.***

Question:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How many binary strings of length 2n + 1 have more 1's than 0's? Use bijection to prove.

Progress so far:

We need a set of known size, B, along with a bijective function $f: A \rightarrow B$, where A is the set with binary strings of length $2n + 1$ and where each element in A has more 1's than 0's.

I tried to find a pattern by setting n = 1:

$$ 
\begin{align*}
000 \rightarrow &\lbrace empty set \rbrace \\
001 \rightarrow &\lbrace 1 \rbrace \\
010 \rightarrow &\lbrace 2 \rbrace \\
011 \rightarrow &\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace \\
100 \rightarrow &\lbrace 3 \rbrace \\
101 \rightarrow &\lbrace 1,3 \rbrace \\
110 \rightarrow &\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace \\
111 \rightarrow &\lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace \\
\end{align*}
$$

I realized that binary strings with more 1's than 0's map to elements in B where the elements are of size $\geq 2n$.

Therefore the size of set $S$ where $S = \lbrace x : |x| \geq 2n\rbrace$ is the number of binary strings of length $2n+1$ with more 1's than 0's.

This is where I am stuck. I don't know how to fit bijection into this solution. Also I think my mapping from set A to set B is incorrect since set A it should only contain the binary strings that have more 1's than 0's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:  First, note that since your string has odd length, every binary string has either more 1's or more 0's (no ties).  Suppose that a string has more 0's than 1's... what happens when you flip all the bits?  The new string has more 1's than 0's.  So, for your bijection, consider pairing up a string with it's complement (i.e. the string with all the 1's and 0's flipped).

What you see by this bijection is that for every string with more 1's than 0's there is a corresponding string with more 0's than 1's.

Following your example, what you would pair up are the following:

$000 \to 111$

$001 \to 110$

$010 \to 101$

$100 \to 011$

That accounts for all 8 binary strings of length 3.  Note that he LHS are the strings with fewer 1's than 0's and the RHS are the strings with more 1's than 0's.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to break down the question with the hints you just provided.

Comment: @mustrah, great.  So think about what two sets your bijection is between and what it means in terms of cardinality of those two sets.

Comment: How did you pick the LHS? For $n=3$ its straight forward but I am trying to generalize it for any n.

Comment: @mustrah, the LHS are the strings with more 0's than 1's and the RHS is the complement of those strings.  Each element on the LHS is paired with it's complement on the RHS.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If we toss a fair coin $2015$ times, the probability there are more heads than tails is, by symmetry, equal to the probability there are more tails than heads. We cannot have equality, so the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is definitely the intuition... there is nothing special about the heads or tails (0's or 1's) so no reason why there'd be more strings with more 1's than strings with more 0's.

Comment: I wrote this partly to show that probability can be used to do combinatorics (the other direction is the usual one). More interestingly, one can use properties of means, including conditional expectation arguments, to prove non-probabilistic results.

Comment: I assume you must have read (and are probably a fan of) Alon & Spencer "The probabilistic method"?

Comment: Very much so, although I used the ideas only once, in work on probabilistic distributed algorithms.

Comment: That sounds cool... we should chat sometime.  I got my degree (PhD) doing extremal combinatorics and am now in CS doing High Performance Computing.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to consider this question for a moment: How many binary strings of length $2n + 1$ have more **zeros** than ones? How could you relate one problem to the other?